# Stress test WebPage with javascript

Tags: java, javascript, html, stress-testing

I need to stress test a Microstrategy report call, and write down the data traffic and load time of each parallel call.
Basically, I have a URL, and need to be able to count those two variables until the page is fully loaded.
The problem I encountered, is that many tests I tryed (like JMeter and pure HTTP requests) doesn't know when the inside frame of Microstrategy ends recovering the report.

Any suggestions or different approach?

Thanks in advance